# The file /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/bin/127.0.0.1:8000 does not exist

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run debug my project in PyCharm:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

There comes an issue:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The Error information is bellow:

> The file /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/bin/127.0.0.1:8000 does not exist

My configuration of my project Debug:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

I tried use fix button to fix it, but seems not work:

In there I set the Default Browser.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>